# C# Expression to add values of properties of two objects

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I need an efficient way for summing arbitrary properties in two objects of the same type.

I have a class with a large number of properties of different numerical types:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public long Field2 { get; set; }
    public float Field3 { get; set; }
    public double Field4 { get; set; }
    //...
    public uint Field100 { get; set; }
}
```

At runtime, I allow users to select an arbitrary subset of those fields:

```
List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>();//Field1, Field5, Field99 etc...
```

I then need to iterate over all selected properties on two objects, sum them, and assign back to the first object:

```
MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();
MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();

SumProps(mc1, mc2, props);
```

Which for the example above using fields 1, 5 and 99, would have the effect of doing:

```
mc1.Field1 += mc2.Field1;
mc1.Field5 += mc2.Field5;
mc1.Field99 += mc2.Field99;
```

I am currently using reflection with `PropertyInfo.GetValue()/SetValue()` and manually casting to the appropriate type. This is far too slow since this is a performance critical part of the code that will get called billions of times.

So I need a way of generating an Expression Lambda which will generate the code for summing all requested fields, using the appropriate types. I will then call that lambda like:

```
MySumPropsLambda(c1, c2);
```

From what I've researched it will involve `BlockExpression` and `Expression.AddAssign` but I can't quite wrap my head around how to actually accomplish it.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5.1

**Edit:** Thanks to Akash Kava below, I've made a slight modification and am using this solution:

```
public static Action<T, T> MakePropertySummationAction<T>(PropertyInfo[] props)
    {
        var mc1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var mc2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var exps = new List<Expression>();

        foreach (var pi in props)
        {
            var p1 = Expression.Property(mc1, pi.Name);
            var p2 = Expression.Property(mc2, pi.Name);
            exps.Add(Expression.AddAssign(p1, p2));
        }

        var blockExpr = Expression.Block(exps);
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, T>>(blockExpr, mc1, mc2).Compile();
    }
```

Printing the block expression strings proves it's generated the desired code:

```
(Param_0.Field1 += Param_1.Field1) 
(Param_0.Field2 += Param_1.Field2) 
(Param_0.Field3 += Param_1.Field3) 
(Param_0.Field4 += Param_1.Field4)
```

Performance for doing one million summations in milliseconds:

```
Direct took 4.8ms
Compiled lambda took 177.5ms
Reflection took 5376.7ms
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem completely hence the comment instead of an answer, but out of curiosity why can't you use proper  Data Structure e.g a Dictionary to do this?

Comment: Code smell alert! A class with a large number of numeric properties is not a good idea. Can you use arrays of values instead?

Comment: You could try using a code generator like T4 to generate `Add` methods that do what you want.  You'd have to use reflection to tell the generator how to scan your type's properties at build time, but then there would be no overhead at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Working fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/xPrXXG

```
mc1.Field1 += mc2.Field2;
```

Lambda Expression equivalent is....

```
Action<MyClass,MyClass> CreateMethod(string propertyName){

   var mc1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass));
   var mc2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass));
   var p1 = Expression.Property(mc1, propertyName);
   var p2 = Expression.Property(mc2, propertyName);

   var assign = Expression.AddAssign(p1,p2);

   return Expression.Lambda<Action<MyClass,MyClass>>
            (assign,mc1,mc2).Compile();
}
```

You can call as...

```
var addAssign1 = CreateMethod("Field1");

// equivalent to mc1.Field1 += mc2.Field1;
addAssign1(mc1,mc2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is operator overloading:

Example, say you have T a, and T b,
you could do:

```
    public class T{
        public int Field1{get;set;}
        public static T operator +(T c1, T c2) 
       {

          return new T{Field1=c1.Field1+c2.Field1;}
       }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
T a,b; //initilaize here
T c= a+b;
```

To get  a new compiled value as the sum of a and b

Edit : Formatting is awful

Comment: How do you expect to add Field1, Field2, .... and many more, will you define operator for each field?

Comment: This is design-time code, that is, you're writing actual code by hand then compiling it and running it. The question is asking about run-time code, creating compiled code *at runtime* from runtime data structures.